# How can I make a column reference a row in another table?

Tags: macos, ipad, numbers

I have this table that was created by using the "Form sheet" on iPad

```
Table A
-------------------------------------
Month   | Rent | Groceries | Netflix |
January |  100 |       100 |     100 |
February|  200 |       200 |     200 |
-------------------------------------
```

Naturally, it's weird that the months are the columns, and not the rows. So I want to create a 2nd table that references this table, but transposed

```
Table B
---------------------------------
Description | January | February |
Rent        |     100 |      200 |
Groceries   |     100 |      200 |
```

I can make the Cell reference the other table, but when I click+drag to autocomplete the remaining cells (around 20), they follow the column.

`Table B January Groceries`  points to `Table A February Rent`.

Of course I could do it manually but it'll take me a few hours, and I'll have to manually update each table if I insert a new column on Table A

Answer (score 0):

Other than making a copy of the table you create through forms and manually transposing it via [the table tools transpose menu option](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/numbers-ipad/tan0403655e1/ipados) in iPad Numbers, there is no practical way of creating a new table with switched columns and rows out of an existing table.

In iPad Numbers, after making a copy of your table, tap on the new copy’s top-left corner to select it and bring out the table tools menu.  Tap in the bottom-right corner of the screen in that menu, and then tap Transpose Rows and Columns.

Unfortunately, the transposed table needs to be recreated manually whenever you add new records to the original table or update the existing ones.